# how to load rational numbers in Oracle database

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I have a data file with numbers with this format :

```
xx.xx (example : 0.3)
```

I have to transform them with a comma instead of the point to be loaded in the database. Here is my control file:

```
LOAD DATA
REPLACE
INTO TABLE USER.MYTABLE
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '$'
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(FIELD1,FIELD2,FIELD3,FIELD4,FIELD5,
NUMBER_FIELD "to_number(replace(:NUMBER_FIELD, '.', ','))",
FIELD6,FIELD7,FIELD8)
```

It works good but 0.3 becomes ,3 with no zero. What is wrong there ?

Thank you

I changed my control file as suggested :

```
LOAD DATA
REPLACE
INTO TABLE USER.MYTABLE
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '$'
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(FIELD1 DECIMAL(6,0),
FIELD2 VARCHAR,
FIELD3 VARCHAR,
FIELD4 VARCHAR,
FIELD5 VARCHAR,
FIELD6 FLOAT,
FIELD7 FLOAT,
FIELD8 DATE,
FIELD9 VARCHAR)
```

data lines like this :

1$005$05$1$blablabla$0.50$0$01/02/1996$01

I have errors.

Log file :

```
   Column Name                  Position   Len  Term Encl Datatype
```

---

```
FIELD1     FIRST     4           PACKED DECIMAL (6, 0)
FIELD2     NEXT     *           VARCHAR              
FIELD3     NEXT     *           VARCHAR              
FIELD4                                   NEXT     *           VARCHAR              
FIELD5     NEXT     *           VARCHAR              
FIELD6     NEXT     4           FLOAT                
FIELD7     NEXT     4           FLOAT                
FIELD8     NEXT     *   $       DATE DD/MM/YYYY      
FIELD9     NEXT     *           VARCHAR
```

1. I dont know how the lenght is calculated but it is wrong
2. I have error on FIELD1 : Value larger than specified precision allows for this column.
3. Error on date field says that the day of the month must be between 1 and last day of the month.

Comment: If you have a new problem, please ask a new question. Include the DDL for the table you're loading into, and maybe some actual bad data (from the .bad file). But I'd only specify the field types where it matters - drop the  `VARCHAR` specification, and the `DECIMAL` - that should implicitly convert. For the date one, are the values in the file DD/MM/YYYY, or actually MM/DD/YYYY - the error suggests the latter. [You can specify the format mask](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/ldr_field_list.htm#sthref792).

Comment: No it is DD/MM/YYYY in the file but finally I dont specify the date and it is implicitly converted. So it is resolved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The session you are querying the number in is formatting it as `,3` partly because of your NLS settings. From your profile you are in France so your NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTER_SETTING will be `',.'`, so the decimal separator is a comma. In SQL*Plus and SQL Developer worksheets the default number format doesn't show a leading zero. If you want to see the leading zero you need to specify the format:

```
select to_char(number_field, 'FM9990D999') from mytable
```

which will use your session's decimal separator; or force that with:

```
select to_char(number_field, 'FM9990D999', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS='',.''') from mytable
```

The `FM` stops is leaving *trailing* zeros after the decimal point; if you want to see those then leave that modifier out.

The conversion you are doing on load shouldn't be necessary; you can change the control file to have:

```
NUMBER_FIELD FLOAT,
```

and it will be automatically treated as a number (which always has a period decimal separator). That is cleaner than treating the `:NUMBER_FIELD` as a string, doing the 'decimal' replacement, and then converting to a number using your NLS settings.

You could also specify the NLS settings the other way:

```
NUMBER_FIELD "to_number(:NUMBER_FIELD, '9999D999', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS=''.,''')",
```

When you specify a number format, for `to_number()` or `to_char()`, you obviously need to allow enough 0/9 placeholder each side of the decimal character for the data you actually have. If you don't know, or don't want to specify, the number of digits then you could set NLS_LANG to a territory that uses a period as a decimal separator before running SQL*Loader, and just do `"to_number(:NUMBER_FIELD)"`. Using `FLOAT` is simpler though.

Comment: @mlwacosmos - I'm telling you the loading was good (but have given alternative anyway); and that numbers don't have an intrinsic format; and how you can *display* your numbers with the zero before the decimal separator. Which is what mathguy is showing as well.

Answer (score 1):

It is much, much better to store numbers as numbers (they are not formatted in any way, only the value is stored), then you can do all numeric operations on them very easily, and only format the OUTPUT when you write a query and extract data from the DB, perhaps after numeric manipulations on the stored data.

Regardless, below I illustrate how to get different character formats from numbers. Take a look at the Oracle documentation for `to_char(number)` for more possibilities. The output is based on my session's NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS, which is . for decimals and , for thousands separator.

```
select 0.3 as nmbr, to_char(0.3, '9.99') as str1, to_char(0.3, '0.00') as str2, 
       to_char(0.3, '0D0', 'nls_numeric_characters='',.''') as str3 from dual;

      NMBR STR1  STR2  STR3
---------- ----- ----- ----
        .3   .30  0.30  0,3
```

Comment: It looks like it *is* stored as a number; the load is explicitly calling `to_number()`, to avoid implicit conversion issues from the NLS settings. I think.

Comment: @AlexPoole -  I didn't mean to imply that the current code doesn't load/store the value as a number. Rather, since the OP talked about "transforming them with a comma" before loading, this could mean he might consider changing it to something that would store a char value. I was simply sharing my opinion that that wouldn't be optimal.  Cheers!

Comment: I agree with you and numbers are indeed stored like numbers. Though, Oracle configuration, the comma is used to recognize numbers that is why when loading from data file to database, for oracle numbers are not in the good format.

Answer (score 0):

numbers cannot contain a comma.  What you're trying to do is use the to_number function to create a string rather than a number.  to_char would maybe produce the result you want

Comment: A string - which is what `replace()` will give you - that is being converted to a number can have comma; in this case `to_number()` is converting that string to a number using the NLS settings, which must have comma defined as the decimal separator. You can't use he `to_number` function to create a string...